# Convert RGB image to black and white

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, rgb

I have the following RGB image (shape of (3, 50, 200)):

[image]

I want to reduce dimensions by converting the image to pure black and white (this image looks black and white, but actually it has 3 channels as I mentioned).

I made (with help from the internet) the following function:

```
def rgb2gray(rgb):
    r, g, b = rgb[:,:,0], rgb[:,:,1], rgb[:,:,2]
    gray = (0.2989 * r + 0.5870 * g + 0.1140 * b)
    for x in range(rgb.shape[1]):
      for y in range(rgb.shape[0]):
        if gray[y][x]>128: #if bright
          gray[y][x] = 255.0 #white
        else:
          gray[y][x] = 0.0 #black
    return gray
```

Then I ran:

```
im = cv2.imread("samples/55y2m.png")
print(im.shape)
print(rgb2gray(im).shape)
plt.imshow(rgb2gray(im))
```

And got the following output:

```
(50, 200, 3) #for the input
(50, 200)    #for the output
```

Why the image is yellow and purple, and how can I change it to black and white?

p.s. I tried to change the function to:

```
def rgb2gray(rgb):
    r, g, b = rgb[:,:,0], rgb[:,:,1], rgb[:,:,2]
    gray = (0.2989 * r + 0.5870 * g + 0.1140 * b)

    for x in range(rgb.shape[1]):
      for y in range(rgb.shape[0]):
        if gray[y][x]>128:
          rgb[y][x] = 255.0 #changed
        else:
          rgb[y][x] = 0.0 #changed
    return rgb #changed
```

And I actually got pure black and white image, but it was 3 channels (RGB). So I tried to remove the last axis, and got purple and yellow again.

[image]

Comment: You need to specify a colormap. Default is 'viridis' which contains the yellow and purple. So, `plt.imshow(rgb2gray(im), cm='gray')`.

Comment: Just so you know, `cv2` already has functions to convert a color image to grayscale, and to threshold an image based on brightness.

Comment: It looks like you can simply read the image as Grayscale: `im = cv2.imread("samples/55y2m.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`. You can also display the gray image using OpenCV: `cv2.imshow('im', im)` and `cv2.waitKey(0)` (without setting a colormap).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need this:

```
r, g, b = rgb[:,:,0], rgb[:,:,1], rgb[:,:,2]
gray = (0.2989 * r + 0.5870 * g + 0.1140 * b)
```

because your image is already grayscale, which means `R == G == B`, so you may take GREEN channel (or any other if you like) and use it.

And yeah, specify the colormap for `matplotlib`:

```
plt.imshow(im[:,:,1], cmap='gray')
```

Comment: Thanks, but it matplotlib told me that AttributeError: 'AxesImage' object has no property 'cm', so when I changed it to "cmap" it worked.

Comment: @Yagel sorry for the typo, fixed.